# Get values of checked checkbox to Javascript?

Tags: javascript

**My code is**

```html
<div class="textbox_pizza" id="pizza" disabled="true" onchange="controlinfo(); return false;">
                <span><label>Margherita</label><input type="checkbox" name="pizza" id="margherita"  value="12"></span>
                <span><label>Quattro Formaggi</label><input type="checkbox" name="pizza" id="quattroformaggi" value="12.5"></span>
                <span><label>Capricciosa</label><input type="checkbox" name="pizza" id="capricciosa" value="13"></span>
            </div>
```

Is there any way to get checked check-box values and subtotal all numbers in Javascript, but not to use event boxes?

Comment: What's an event box?

Comment: Please share whatever you have tried. That will act as a starting point to guide you towards your solution

Comment: [Javascript checkbox sum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47582330)? Also see: [How get total sum from input box values using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13540751) | [How to get all checked checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8563240)